# Why does retrofit throw an exception before Observable is created?

Tags: retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I'm testing edge cases with no internet access.
When I call

```
Observable<SomeResponse> responseObservable = client.getMethodNameRedacted("string");
```

Retrofit throws the following error when proceeding in the request chain inside the interceptor:

```
V/CustomLoggingInterceptor$Logger: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "{redacted}": No address associated with hostname
```

So I cannot handle the error in the observable.

Is there some way to wrap the observable to handle this error?

EDIT:
The logging interceptor is just a slightly modified OkHttpLoggingInterceptor to filter logging by content type. It does not affect request chains at all.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the response object in an actual Response object worked